# Verifying WCF2 passwords in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, wcf

I am currently stuck at verifying Wotlab's WCF2 passwords in Node.js.
I tried using Blowfish verifying using bcrypt's `compareSync` but without success.

After looking at https://github.com/WoltLab/WCF/blob/master/wcfsetup/install/files/lib/util/PasswordUtil.class.php I see WoltLab is using some kind of own encryption which is similiar to Blowfish.
I tried porting their class to JavaScript but without success because I am missing a  possibility to use PHP's `crypt()` method within JavaScript.

I encrypted a password using `crypt()` in PHP and added it hard-coded but [this](https://github.com/WoltLab/WCF/blob/master/wcfsetup/install/files/lib/util/PasswordUtil.class.php#L251) line returns false for me.

Hopefully you can help me out.

Kind regards,
Cludch

Comment: Did you found an answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry

Comment: Did you tried some things out ? Can it be the solution to double salt and md5 the password and check if it compare to the hash ?

Comment: I tried to port the whole password class of WCF2 but there were a few things I couldn't port that easily and since my supervisior told me to focus on something else, I moved on.

Comment: Sad to hear. If you get something, let me hear.

Comment: Could you send me your modded class of WCF2 ?

Comment: It's on my works git. Even if I had a copy, I wouldn't be allowed to, sorry :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127133/discussion-between-marvin-heilemann-and-cludch).